# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'ServiceWorker': function could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am trying to post a message to a service worker instance. I get the following error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'ServiceWorker': function (){
>         obj.removeListener(ev, fn);
>       } could not be cloned.

My code is as follows:

```
var socket = io();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    //Tell the service worker who I am
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(serviceWorkerRegistration => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
            name: 'socketInit',
            value: socket
        });
    });
}
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually found the answer right away, it's in the docs. You basically can't have a `Function`-type property (*which probably is there somewhere inside the io() object*) because it can't be cloned:

> **Parameters**  
>  `message` 
>    The message to send to the service worker. This can be **any
>   structured-clonable type**.

A `structured-clonable-type` being defined as:

> The structured clone algorithm is an algorithm defined by the HTML5
>   specification for copying complex JavaScript objects. It is used
>   internally when transferring data to and from Workers via
>   postMessage(). It builds up a clone by recursing through the input
>   object while maintaining a map of previously visited references in
>   order to avoid infinitely traversing cycles.
>
> **Things that don't work with structured clone**
>
> **Error** and **Function** objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a
>   **DATA_CLONE_ERR** exception. Attempting to clone DOM nodes will likewise
>   throw a **DATA_CLONE_ERR** exception. Certain parameters of objects are
>   not preserved: The lastIndex field of RegExp objects is not preserved.
>   Property descriptors, setters, and getters (as well as similar
>   metadata-like features) are not duplicated. For example, if an object
>   is marked read-only using a property descriptor, it will be read-write
>   in the duplicate, since that's the default condition. The prototype
>   chain does not get walked and duplicated.

Comment: Hi how do you achieve instantiating sockets from service workers, I tried doing this and ran to the same problem as above.

Comment: hey @ArausiDaniel , I've been in this exact dilemma since last Friday. Did you manage to solve this problem? did you find the answer?