# DataCloneError from webpack

Tags: webpack, postmessage, webpack-4

In our crash tracking system bugsnag, I see lots of DataCloneError with the following message:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': 
function (e,t,n){"use strict";e.exports=n(1360)} could not be cloned.
```

The time when these first appeared matches upgrading to webpack 4. We're using vendor split to separate our bundle to vendor~app.js and app.js, which are added on the page in that order. The function in the error message appears in the very first part of vendor~app.js.

The error happens with multiple browsers and OS:s, but I've not been able to reproduce it myself. The site where this happens is https://wolt.com

What could cause this crash?

Answer (score 2):

The error is definitely caused by passing a function to `window.postMessage()` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46145497/6571327) as to why passing a function doesn't work).  The question is who's calling it?  In my case, it was an extension I had running (angular augury).  I found this by stubbing window.postMessage:

```
window._postMessage = window.postMessage
function f(...args){
  console.log({args})
  window._postMessage(...args)
  throw new Error('stack trace please')
}
window.postMessage = f
```

Searching your source code via the firefox debugger found several instances of `window.postMessage` being called, including some communication with iframes. It wasn't clear which one, if any, would regularly throw errors.

Comment: Thanks Steven, this didn't quite solve the problem yet but you gave an outside confirmation that we're looking in the right direction, so I gave you the bounty.