# Get width/height of pixels array in Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I am using TypeScript on Deno. I am trying to use [blurhash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blurhash).

This is my code:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
if (!response.body) {
throw new Error("Body null");
}

const clamped = new Uint8ClampedArray(await response.arrayBuffer());
var blurhash: string = encode(clamped, width, height, 4, 4,);
```

where `width` and `height` is known beforehand. But I get this error:

`Width and height must match the pixels array`

I read this [issue](https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash/issues/107) and it seems like the alpha channel is missing or something. The problem is, that all solutions are fixing it by using `sharp` with `ensureAlpha()`. But `sharp` is not running on Deno, so I can't use it.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: according to `sharp` documentation ... *It can be used with all JavaScript runtimes that provide support for Node-API v9, including Node.js (^18.17.0 or >= 20.3.0), Deno and Bun.* - perhaps you're doing it wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX Mhh okay. For me it is not working. I am just getting a `segmentation fault`. But I am in a `supabase` environment. Maybe that is causing issues.

Comment: You might find this to be a useful read: [Efficiently update a canvas with RGB or grayscale data (but not RGBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73191734/438273)

Comment: @JaromandaX It doesn't seem to be fully supported, see [here](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2583)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blurhash library you are using expects an Uint8Array of raw bitmap pixels in the format `[R, G, B, A]`. Here you are feeding it the whole png file, with its headers, its metadata and the pixel data compressed in it.

You will need to actually read that image file in order to gain access to this raw bitmap data. There are various libraries that do that, I'll let you pick one, but unfortunately deno ones require CSP rules that we don't have here in StackSnippet so I can 't make a live demo.

```
import * as blurhash from "https://esm.sh/blurhash";
// Or any other library
import decode from "https://deno.land/x/wasm_image_decoder@v0.0.7/mod.js";

const response = await fetch(url);
if (!response.body) {
  throw new Error("Body null");
}
const fileBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const { data, width, height } = await decode(fileBuffer);
const hash = encode(data, width, height, 4, 4,);
console.log(hash);
```

Comment: I get `Property 'buffer' does not exist on type 'Response'.`. Do you mean `arrayBuffer()`?

Comment: @progNewbie yes that was a typo

Comment: Somehow I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'wasmImageDecoder' does not provide an export named 'decode'` after importing it like `import { decode } from "wasmImageDecoder"` with my import_map entry `"wasmImageDecoder": "https://deno.land/x/wasm_image_decoder@v0.0.7/mod.js"`

Comment: I thought I fixed that by importing directly from `https://deno.land/x/wasm_image_decoder@v0.0.7/wasm/wasm_image_decoder.js`. But Now I get this [error](https://github.com/josephrocca/wasm-image-decoder/issues/6)

Comment: I made it work by using another lib. thank you!